# How can the newer pandas(>=v1.2.5?) read an Excel file with different encoding?

Tags: python, pandas

Current(>=v1.2.5?) pandas.read_excel() method removed an argument "encoding=".

-Ref: [read_excel() @ Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Please tell me how pandas reads shift-jis(cp932) based an excel file with encoding UTF8?
(The excel created in windows(cp932). I want to read in MacOS(utf8))

- `pandas.read_excel(open('file_path','rb',encoding="utf8"))` caused an error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running read_excel without the encoding argument?

It seems to have worked for some people since the removal. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/35753

Comment: Yes, I done, and got character corruption on Japanese in header of the data frame from an excel file. I already read the above url.

Comment: Thank you your adovice, Nick G. I ask my question to the above thread.